# How to compute index of n'th element in a binary search tree?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm storing a binary search tree (BST) in an array where the indices of the left and right children of each node are computed as follows:

```
N = parent node index
L = 2 * N + 1
R = 2 * N + 2
```

I would like to be able to quickly (ideally in O(1) time) compute the index of the n'th element in the BST.

For example, given the following binary tree ...

```
      A
    /   \
  B       C
 / \     /
D   E   F
```

... which would be stored in an array, like this ...

```
Node array[] = { A, B, C, D, E, F };
```

The following table shows which should be the index for each element.

| Element | Node | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | D | 3 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 2 | E | 4 |
| 3 | A | 0 |
| 4 | F | 5 |
| 5 | C | 2 |

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

**Note:** The BST will *always* be perfectly balanced ...

Answer (score 0):

To find the index, we need to know what layer of the tree it's in, and what item in that layer it is.

Let's number the layers from the bottom up, starting at 1. Then, the layer of each item is `1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1,,2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, ...`. This is pretty much the sequence `gcd(n, 2^n)`, which looks just like a BST:
[image: gcd(n, 2^n) graph]

You can calculate this using the euclidean algorithm, in O(log n) time.

To work out where in the layer this item appears, we can observe that the distances between indices in the same layer is `2^layer` (you can see this by counting the spaces in the graph.

Combining these pieces of information, you should be able to get an index.

Answer (score 0):

When recursing the tree, you can compute the index of each node using:

```
root.left.index  = 2 * root.index + 1
root.right.index = 2 * root.index + 2
```